# How to make qmake compile multiple cross platform binaries

Tags: compilation, qt-creator, qmake, multiplatform

I'm using QT Creator on a project and was wondering if there's a single command to compile the project to a Mac, Windows, & Linux binaries so I can easily send them to other computers for testing without having to send over the whole source code. Currently I'm running the QT Creator on Mac OSX if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but it isn't as simple as you imply.  To properly do this, you would need to set up a cross-compiling environment complete with libraries already compiled for the other platforms, and compilers/executables compiled for your platform that produce output for the other platform.  You would then need to keep track of all these variables somehow in your qmake file to be sure you're producing the correct output.